# Can't change border for Google visualization table

Tags: google-visualization, border

I tried cssClassNames for google visualization table chart. Fonts, backgrounds changed. But I have no idea of hiding or changing table border. On google's link below there are border weight and color assigned, but not changed.

Google's tutorial: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples?hl=fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could customize table border via `tableCell` as demonstrated below

**Example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table', 'gauge', 'corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
  var cssClassNames = {
    'headerRow': '',
    'tableRow': '',
    'oddTableRow': '',
    'selectedTableRow': '',
    'hoverTableRow': '',
    'headerCell': '',
    'tableCell': 'custom-table-td',
    'rowNumberCell': ''};

  var options = {'showRowNumber': true, 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames};

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time');
  data.addRows(5);
  data.setCell(0, 0, 'John');
  data.setCell(0, 1, 10000, '$10,000');
  data.setCell(0, 2, true);
  data.setCell(1, 0, 'Mary');
  data.setCell(1, 1, 25000, '$25,000');
  data.setCell(1, 2, true);
  data.setCell(2, 0, 'Steve');
  data.setCell(2, 1, 8000, '$8,000');
  data.setCell(2, 2, false);
  data.setCell(3, 0, 'Ellen');
  data.setCell(3, 1, 20000, '$20,000');
  data.setCell(3, 2, true);
  data.setCell(4, 0, 'Mike');
  data.setCell(4, 1, 12000, '$12,000');
  data.setCell(4, 2, false);
  var container = document.getElementById('table');
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  table.draw(data, options);
  
}
```

```css
.google-visualization-table-table td.custom-table-td {
    border: solid green;
    border-width: 2px 2px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: @Nargil, to customize row style, you might want 1) set `tableRow:custom-table-tr` style and define `.google-visualization-table-table tr.custom-table-tr` style   P.S. Nice to hear that you visited Irkutsk and speak some Russian Удачи! :)

Comment: Thank you Vadim. I could change borders for th and td elements. But how to change border around table? I still see white border.